# Can malicious code, virus, etc be loaded onto a site that accepts embed links?

Tags: embedding, virus, video-embedding

I operate a CMS Site (Video Server like YouTube-like)and it permits users to embed links to videos elsewhere on the web, i.e. www.vimeo.com/videos/sjek3469df

Is there any way someone could input any type or URL "link" that could infect my website?

Thanks in advance all!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how your site is set up, but yes, there would be XSS concerns. At the very least, I'd suggest a whitelist for allowed video hosts (with particular URL patterns, not just acceptable domains). You should also consider parsing the URLs to obtain the video IDs, and using those to generate your own embedding code on a per-host basis. That would give you more customization power, not just more security.